# Absolutely positioned elements collapse

Tags: html, css

I have some absolutely positioned elements:

```css
span {
  display: block;
}

span.sub {
  color: blue;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Coffee</span>
  <span class="sub">Tea</span>
  <span class="sub">Milk</span>
  <span class="sub">Water</span>
</div>
```

How can I prevent them from collapsing?  I want them to flow freely over the elements under `div`, like a dropdown navigation menu. Can it be achieved without nesting the positioned elements inside an extra container?

Comment: Absolutely positioned elements don’t affect anything around them so giving them dimensions doesn’t alter anything else. Is there a reason for not having them position e.g. relative?

Comment: @AHaworth: "Is there a reason for not having them position e.g. relative?" I want them to flow freely over the elements under `div`, like a navigation dropdown menu.

Comment: Would putting them all into one absolutely positioned div be the answer then?

Comment: Of course, but I wonder if I can achieve the same effect without adding an extra element.

Comment: As far as I can work out, only by positioning them individually which is a bit messy, but I've put it in an answer just in case of use.

Comment: if you want them one below another then why do you want to use position absolute? you can even achieve this by display property

Comment: can you take screen shot from ui

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One approach could be using `white-space: pre;` on parent div:

```css
    span {
      display: block;
    }

    span.sub {
      color: blue;
      position: absolute;
    }


    /* --------------------- */

    :root {
      /* 1em is default font size */
      --menu-bar-height: 1.3em;
    }

    body div {
      
      width: 200px;
      background-color: rgb(122, 213, 243);

      height: var(--menu-bar-height);
      white-space: pre;
    }

    span:first-child {
      margin-top: -2em;
      width: fit-content;
      background-color: rgb(48, 171, 212);
    }

    span.sub {
      margin-top: -2.4em;
    }


    /* cosmetic changes */
    .sub:hover {
      border: 2px dotted blue;
      transform: translateX(10px);
    }

    .sub:nth-child(even) {
      background-color: lawngreen;
    }

    .sub:nth-child(odd) {
      background-color: tomato;
    }

    #second {
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
      background-color: wheat;
      text-align: center;
      z-index: -1;
    }
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Coffee</span>
  <span class="sub">Tea</span>
  <span class="sub">Milk</span>
  <span class="sub">Water</span>
  <span class="sub">Chocolate</span>
</div>
<div id="second">Div 2</div>
```

---

Following is one more approach. Using `white-space: pre;` on span:before  pseudo element and adding more lines using counter.

```css
span {
      display: block;
    }

    span.sub {
      color: blue;
      position: absolute;
    }


    /* --------------------- */

    @counter-style nuLine {
      system: symbolic;
      symbols: "\a";
    }

    body div:first-child {
      width: 200px;
      counter-reset: lines;
      background-color: lightblue;
      flex-direction: column-reverse;
    }

    span.sub {
      height: 0px;
      margin-top: -1em;
      background-color: transparent;
      mix-blend-mode: multiply;
    }

    span.sub::before {
      counter-increment: lines;
      content: counter(lines, nuLine) counter(lines) ". ";
      white-space: pre;
    }

    span.sub::after {
      content: "\00a0";
      width: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      left: 0px;
      opacity: .5;
    }


    /* cosmetic changes */
    span:first-child {
      width: 200px;
    }

    .sub:hover {
      transform: translateX(10px);
    }

    .sub:hover::after {
      border: 2px dotted blue;
    }

    .sub:nth-child(even)::after {
      background-color: lawngreen;
    }

    .sub:nth-child(odd)::after {
      background-color: tomato;
    }

    #second {
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
      background-color: wheat;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 0px;
      margin: 0px;
    }
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Coffee</span>
  <span class="sub">Tea</span>
  <span class="sub">Milk</span>
  <span class="sub">Water</span>
  <span class="sub">Chocolate</span>
</div>

<div id="second">Div 2</div>
```

Comment: Your first approach seems interesting, but it doesn't work well if you add other elements to the page, e.g. another `div` under it.

Comment: adding `height` solved the issue. Run the updated first approach code. I hope this is how you want it to behave.

Comment: fixed second approach too. output looks almost same as first approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this. Apply absolute positioning on the parent `div`. This will make the whole parent element be absolutely positioned above any kind of other content - like a *dropdown menu* as you mentioned - while the child `span` will flow normally inside this element.

```css
div {
  position:absolute;
}

span {
  display: block;
}

span.sub {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Coffee</span>
  <span class="sub">Tea</span>
  <span class="sub">Milk</span>
  <span class="sub">Water</span>
</div>
```

Comment: whats the point in that? he can just remove the absolute position from the span.sub and get the same "look"

Comment: Without additional sample DOM content you can’t really tell the difference but the OP requested to have the list items to hover above content like a drop down menu, so I provided a better practice solution. Absolute positioning for the spans has in fact been removed,

Answer (score 0):

First of all We need to understand something.

When we use position, we usually need: `position:relative` for the parent element and `position:absolute` for the child elements.

If we give to the children `position:absolute` without using `position:relative` in the parent, this children will be positioned taking the window as reference, soo they will be positioned in the left/top corner of the window, causing like this a collapse.

Second, when using `position:absolute` we also need to tell the child where do we want them using `top, bottom, left, right` you will se in my example.

if we dont use them, they will be positioned in the same spot, causing a collapse.

soo, once expalined this, here is my solution, in my opinion is not the best way to do a dropdown menu.

```
<div>
    <span>Coffee</span>
    <span class="sub">Tea</span>
    <span class="sub">Milk</span>
    <span class="sub">Water</span>
</div>
```

my HTML is the same as you wanted.

```
    div{
        position: relative;
    }
    span {
        display: block;
    }
    span.sub {
        color: blue;
        position: absolute;
    }
    span.sub:nth-child(2){            
        left: 0;
        top: 20px;
        display: none;
    }
    span.sub:nth-child(3){
        left: 0;
        top: 40px;
        display: none;
    }
    span.sub:nth-child(4){
        left: 0;
        top: 60px;
        display: none;
    }

    span:first-child:hover ~ span{
        display: block;
    }
```

notice that I use `left and top` as I told before.

First of all we need the parent element, in this case the div to be `position: relative` because this is our reference.

our span which contains the Coffee word is positioned as it should.

then is quite simple, we need to target each span.sub because they need different values of position not to collapse, I´ve used pseudo-classes to target them, you can also use another class.

and to make a dropdown menu on hover I´ve donee with this line `span:first-child:hover ~ span{display: block;}` when hover on coffee the display of all span.sub will be changed to block to be able to see them.